# Convert a string pair of coordinates to geomtery data type in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, geometry, geospatial, spatial

I have a column in a MongoDB collection with location stored as string pair values:
geometry:"POINT (72.548355 23.042458)"

I need to create a geometry field which works with MongoDB's spatial queries. Something which is in this format:

"geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [72.548355, 23.042458]
},

Please help. I need to run this for billions of entries in the collection. So an optimized solution will be extremely helpful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "geometry": {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            "arr": { $split: [ "$geometry", " " ] }
          },
          in: {
            "type": { 
              $concat: [
                { $toUpper: { $substr: [ { $first: "$$arr" }, 0, 1 ] } },
                { $toLower: { $substr: [ { $first: "$$arr" }, 1, { $strLenCP: { $first: "$$arr" } } ] } }
              ] 
             },
            "coordinates": [
              {
                $toDouble:{
                  $ltrim: {
                    input: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$arr", 1 ] },
                    chars: "("
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                $toDouble:{
                  $rtrim: {
                    input: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$arr", 2 ] },
                    chars: ")"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{ "multi": true })
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rfAbztMEK2n)

Comment: Thank you, @YuTing, it works for me. In your code array is returning the values in string format, and I need values in integer format.

Comment: @NarayanDas  I update my answer with `$toDouble`

Comment: In this code how may I use $toUpper query, to capitalize the first latter of POINT.
before this query, in your code. Thank you alot
in: {

            "type": { $first: "$$arr" },

Comment: @NarayanDas I update my answer with `$toUpper`

Comment: still I need to capitalize only first letter, rest of them will be in lowercase, "POINT" -> "Point" like that,  

geometry:"POINT (72.548355 23.042458)"
type = "Point"

Comment: @NarayanDas I update my answer with  capitalize only first letter

Comment: would you mind to connect with me, via gmail, whatsapp, discord, linkedIn, Insta or yahoo mail? I am expert in python, So might be I'll also help you if needed. Thanks

Comment: I have billion of entries and that command is running since yesterday. How do I know, how much time it will take?
is there any hint in MongoDB compass interface, which can show us the progress bar?

Comment: @NarayanDas Use [type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) to check how many entries still have `geometry` be the type of `string` and [count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/) it.  [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4iV6o-89wsd)

Comment: Okay, So I've to stop the query. then I'll run type query and count it. But I am beginner in mongodb, So how may restart again the query for remaining geometry those are still not converted in required geom type in same collection.
So I've to use updateMany() or some other keyword, I have to add.

Comment: @NarayanDas You may restart again the query for remaining geometry by add the query to the update [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KFsb4E_InRc). You may open another connection to query how many entries left without stop the update.